# How do i generate links that will display these products depending on the ID from the database to another page (product page) in php

Tags: php, sql

```
<?php                      
    foreach($products as $i => $product): ?>
    <article class="products__card">
        <a href="./product.php?id">
            <img src="<?php echo $product['image'] ?>" alt="" 
        class="product__image">

            <h3 class="products__title"><?php echo 
            $product['Device_name'] ?></h3>
            <span class="products__price"><?php echo 
        number_format($product['price']) ?> UGX</span>
        </a>
        <button class="products__button">
        <i class="uil uil-shopping-bag"></i>
        </button>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $product['id'] 
                    ? 
                >">
    </article>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The sql is okay the column for id exists but I am not sure how to generate pages depending on the id of the clicked item.

Comment: I am actually a student  still learning and this is my  practice project for the semester so please forgive me if i do not meet your "universal coding syntax" but I will learn and i hope you do help me instead of what you are doing.

Comment: @Mustafa Poya  My thanks to Mustafa Poya for cleaning up the post.

Comment: I know I come off as being harsh.  I am often really misunderstood.   And that is the reason I gave myself that screen name.  I really could not deal with that until Mustafa Poya cleaned it up.  I think I took care of how to link and a few other things.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, you need to have a link to the selected product, if that is what you asked, you can create it like this:

```
product.php?id=<?php echo $product['id']; ?>
```

With this you will get an example if your product has 412 ID in the database, the link will be **https://example.com/product.php?id=412**.

And in **product.php** page you need to do something like this:

```
$link = null;

if(!empty($_GET['id'])) {
        $link = $_GET['id'];
}
if (null === $link) {
    header('Location: /index.html');
} else {
    // code
...
```

The first line of code prevents users to manually change id number of your product, in that case, they will be automatically redirected to the index page or else the display page. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The jumping back and forth between PHP mode and HTML mode is inappropriate.
You mention SQL but there is no SQL shown.
Instead of breaking out of PHP into HTML and back just make the strings in PHP and use concatenation to make the string and `echo` it.

```
echo `<a href="./product.php"><img class="product__image" src="' . $product['image'] . '" alt="" />';
```

foreach works with arrays as key-value pairs. Where `i` is your key and `$products`.  If you do not need the key (i) then you do not need to use a key variable.

You should not use associative arrays here.  It is very difficult to embed them in PHP strings. I can show you how to do it correctly but for now I will simplify the variables.  And we can eliminate concatenation.

```
$image = $product['image'];
$price = number_format($product['price']);
$device = $product['Device_name'];
$id = $product['id'];
```

This is not valid, it will show nothing in the Browser

```
<i class="uil uil-shopping-bag"></i>
```

The "i" tag was used to italicize text:

```
<i>The will render in italic print</i>
```

The `<i>` tag was replaced by `<span>`
The img tag ends with `/>`. needs the slash as does `<input ... />`

```
foreach($products as $product){
  echo <<<EOT
    <article class="products__card">
        <a href="./product.php?id">
          <img class="product__image" src="$image" alt="" />
          <h3 class="products__title">$device</h3>
          <span class="products__price">$price UGX</span>
        </a>
        <button class="products__button"></button>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="$id" />
    </article>
EOT;
}
```

Now the link to the product page:
I saw you used and anchor `a href="./product.php">`

And you used `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="$id" />`

You should use a `<form>` and with a POST rather than an anchor GET

```
<form action="./product.php? method="post"><button><img src="icon.jpg" width="20" height="20" /></button><input ="hidden" name="id" value="$id"</form>
```

**NOTE:**  Always specify a `width` and `height` in a `<img>`.  If you do not, it gives the Browser a lot of unnecessary  work to do.

Now the associative array. I assume you got that from mySQL.
This is how I get the column contents.
I use the fetch_array and specify only the numeric array.
I get the numeric array because the `list()` function will assign the value of a numeric array to simple variable.

```
$sql = "SELECT `id`,`Device_name`,`price`,`image` FROM `Products` WHERE 1";
$results = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while(list($id,$device,$price,$image) =  mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_NUM)){
  echo <<<EOT
<article class="products__card">
<img class="product__image" src="$image" alt="" />
<h3 class="products__title">$device</h3>
<span class="products__price">$price UGX</span>
<form action="./product.php? method="post"><button><img src="icon.jpg" width="20" height="20" /></button><input ="hidden" name="id" value="$id"</form>
 </article>
EOT;
}
```